# how to validate if entered date is of today or of future using yup

Tags: javascript, reactjs, yup

This is working for all the cases except for same day,

```
Yup.date()
    .required(“Start Date is required”)
    .test(“startDate”, “Start Date can not be a passed Date”, function (date) {
      const cutoff = new Date();
      const selectedDate = date;
      return selectedDate >= cutoff;
    }),
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of getting the date/time *now* with `new Date()`, set its time to the start of today:

```
const cutoff = new Date();
cutoff.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
```